# SQLite group_concat returns many instances of the same data, can't use DISTINCT

Tags: sqlite, duplicates, left-join, group-concat

I'm trying to return data from 4 tables using JOINs and group_concat

This is my current query:

```
SELECT  m.ID AS num
    , m.Name AS MOVIE
    , group_concat(v.Codec, '-') AS v_CODEC
    , group_concat(a.Codec, '-') AS a_CODEC
    , group_concat(s.Language, '-') AS SUBs
FROM File AS m
LEFT JOIN Video AS v ON m.ID = v.FileID
LEFT JOIN Audio AS a ON m.ID = a.FileID
LEFT JOIN Subtitle AS s ON m.ID = s.FileID
GROUP BY m.ID
ORDER BY m.ID
```

With my current query, my results look like this:

```
+-----+----------+----------------+-------------+----------+
| num |   MOVIE  |     v_CODEC    |   a_CODEC   |   SUBs   |
+-----+----------+----------------+-------------+----------+
| 1   | Superman | H264-H264-H264 | DTS-DTS-DTS | en-en-en |
|     |          | H264-H264-H264 | DTS-DTS-DTS | en-en-en |
+-----+----------+----------------+-------------+----------+
| 2   | Batman   | MPEG2-MPEG2    | MP3-MP3     |          |
+-----+----------+----------------+-------------+----------+
```

I would like my results look like this:

```
+-----+----------+---------+-------------+-------+
| num |   MOVIE  | v_CODEC |   a_CODEC   |  SUBs |
+-----+----------+---------+-------------+-------+
| 1   | Superman | H264    | DTS-DTS-DTS | en-en |
+-----+----------+---------+-------------+-------+
| 2   | Batman   | MPEG2   | MP3-MP3     |       |
+-----+----------+---------+-------------+-------+
```

This is my database estructure:

```
File
+----+----------+
| ID |   Name   |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Superman |
+----+----------+
| 2  | Batman   |
+----+----------+

Video
+--------+-------+
| FileID | Codec |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | H264  |
+--------+-------+
| 2      | MPEG2 |
+--------+-------+

Audio
+--------+-------+
| FileID | Codec |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | DTS   |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | DTS   |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | DTS   |
+--------+-------+
| 2      | MP3   |
+--------+-------+
| 2      | MP3   |
+--------+-------+

Subtitle
+--------+----------+
| FileID | Language |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | en       |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | en       |
+--------+----------+
```

How to make my query to achieve what I need?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `With my current query, my results look like this` ... I doubt your current results really look like this, with multiple values per cell.  Please include the real actual current output.

Comment: I enclosed to my post a picture of my real actual current output.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). PS You don't say in words how your output is a function of inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following is what you want:-

```
SELECT 
    m.ID AS num, 
    m.name AS movie, 
    (SELECT group_concat(codec,'-') FROM Video WHERE FileID = m.ID) AS v_codec, 
    (SELECT group_concat(codec,'-') FROM Audio WHERE FileID = m.ID) AS a_codec,
    (SELECT group_concat(Language,'-') FROM Subtitle WHERE FileID = m.ID) AS SUBs
FROM File AS m ORDER BY m.id;
```

Which produces :-

[image]

That is instead of basing the extract upon the cartesian product that would, without grouping, be some thing like :-

[image]

The answer does the group_concat only upon the relations

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Comment: Read the answer at the link.

Comment: @MikeT Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your kind explanation and help.